# How to focus next field if user clicked on the link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a number of fields with labels-links like below:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="some-id-1"><a href="http://example.com/some-id-1" target="_blank">Text1</a></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="some-id-1" name="some-id-1"><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="some-id-2"><a href="http://example.com/some-id-2" target="_blank">Text2</a></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="some-id-2" name="some-id-2"><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

If user clicks on the link, how can I focus according field (without preventing default action)? I.e. if user clicks on `Text1`, then I should open `http://example.com/some-id-1` in new window and set focus at input with id `some-id-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EkyCt/)

```
$(".control-label a").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().next().find('input').focus();

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't open the link... But it works as expected with `return false;` removed.

Comment: @Sushil  you are acting on current page... OP wants to open new page and set focus there

Comment: @charlietfl I think OP want to open new window and focus to next input on current page.

Comment: This answer solved the problem. I wanted to focus the field on first page.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.control-label a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().next().find('input').focus();
  // or
  $('.control-group').has(this).find('input').focus();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't open the link... and if I remove `preventDefault`, then it doesn't focus the field.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://example.com/some-id-1" target="_blank" onClick="document.getElementById('some-id-1').focus();">Text1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If understanding correctly you want to open a new page and in the new page set focus based on link that was clicked

If you are opening a new page you will need to pass a hash in url or use a cookie and have other page parse the hash or cookie

In current page:

```
$(function(){
    $('.control-label a').click(function(){
       var hash='#'+ $(this).next().find('input').attr('id');
       window.open( this.href + hash);
        return false;
    });
})
```

In other page:

```
$(function(){
    var hash= location.hash;
    $(hash).focus();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript in one page can't control how another page responds to a URL, if the 'other' page is under your control then you could set it up to parse the `id`:

```
var parts = document.location.href.split('/'),
    id = parts.pop();

document.getElementById(id).focus;
```

On the other hand, if you want to focus that element reliably, just pass an `id`, as a `hash`, to the URL:

```
<a href="somepage.html#some-id">Go to an element of 'some id'</a>
```

This may not focus the form element, but it should draw that element to the attention of the user and, in pages outside of your control, is much more reliable.